# How to add a close button to action bar tabs

Tags: button, tabs, android-actionbar

I am building an app and it has an action bar with maximum four tabs.
I would like to add a close button like web browser into action bar tabs.

I know how to add/delete tabs dynamically.
I have been looking for how to add a close button, but I could find nothing!

If you know a solution or tutorial, please tell me.
Or is this(adding close button into tab) a bad practice?

Thanks,

My environment:
Android 4.4.2 (api-level 19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I could solve my problem using ActionBar.Tab#setCustomView method.
It enables to add a view that you make to action bar tabs.

My code is:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setCustomView(R.layout.tab_title)
            .setTabListener(new MainTabListener<TabFragment>( this, "myTab", TabFragment.class
            )));
```

More details of adding tabs to the action bar can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

For instance, my tab_title.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title_tab"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center"
android:singleLine="true"
android:paddingStart="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/close_tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title_tab"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/title_tab"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="x"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, adding a click listener to the TextView of the close button, you can make a close button into action bar tabs.

I hope this post helps someone.

CAUTION:
If you enable device rotation, please be careful this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43213&can=1&q=screen%20rotate%20tab&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars